# Ввод данных в структуру

Tags: c, структуры

Почему я не могу ввести данные в структуру. Все какие-то проблемы с вводом.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

#define N 3

typedef struct {
    char name[25];
    int tel[15];
    int bday[3];
} NOTE;

void setValue(NOTE blockNote[N]);
void printValue(NOTE blockNote[N]);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    NOTE blockNote[N];
    setValue(blockNote);
    printValue(blockNote);
    return 0;
}

void setValue(NOTE blockNote[N]) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        printf("Enter name: ");
        gets_s(blockNote[i].name);
        printf("Enter tel: ");
        printf("%d", &blockNote[i].tel);
        printf("Enter bday (format: day.month.year): ");
        scanf_s("%d.%d.%d", &blockNote[i].bday[0], &blockNote[i].bday[1], &blockNote[i].bday[2]);
        printf("---\n");
    }
}

void printValue(NOTE blockNote[N]) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        printf("name: %s tel: %d bday: %d.%d.%d\n", blockNote[i].name, blockNote[i].tel, blockNote[i].bday[0], blockNote[i].bday[1], blockNote[i].bday[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

typedef struct {
  char name[25];
  int tel;
  int bday[3];
} NOTE;

void setValue(NOTE* blockNote);
void printValue(NOTE* blockNote);

int main() {
  NOTE blockNote[N];
  setValue(blockNote);
  printValue(blockNote);
  return 0;
}

void setValue(NOTE* blockNote) {
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", &blockNote->name);
    printf("Enter tel: ");
    scanf("%d", &blockNote->tel);
    printf("Enter bday (format: day.month.year): ");
    scanf("%d.%d.%d", &blockNote->bday[0], &blockNote->bday[1], &blockNote->bday[2]);
    printf("---\n");
    blockNote++;
  }
}

void printValue(NOTE* blockNote) {
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    printf("name: %s tel: %d bday: %d.%d.%d\n", blockNote->name, blockNote->tel, blockNote->bday[0], blockNote->bday[1], blockNote->bday[2]);
    blockNote++;
  }
}
```

1. Первая ошибка в `int tel[15];`, так как это массив, а вам нужно просто `int tel;`
2. Вторая ошибка в том, что вы передаете в функцию setValue копию структуры, а потом её никак не возвращаете и передаете в функцию printValue тоже копию, то что же должно вывестись?
3. Третья ошибка в `printf("%d", &blockNote[i].tel);`, а должен быть `scanf`.

И хорошо бы проверки делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d", &blockNote[i].tel);
```

А вы уверены, что тут `printf`

А здесь

```
scanf_s("%d.%d.%d", &blockNote[i].bday[0], &blockNote[i].bday[1], &blockNote[i].bday[2]);
```

и здесь

```
printf("name: %s tel: %d bday: %d.%d.%d\n", blockNote[i].name, blockNote[i].tel, blockNote[i].bday[0], blockNote[i].bday[1], blockNote[i].bday[2]);
```

Зачем-то точек натыкали при указании типов `(%d.%d.%d)`

И это далеко не всё, что можно заметить.

Comment: Точки в scanf для того, чтобы можно было ввести 01.01.2013 с точками, а не 01012013. И если в его варианте не ввести эти точки в формате, но ввести 01.01.2013 в консоле, то запишется только первое число 01, а все остальное нет, так как будет искаться точка.